# How to get data of last 3 months from sql table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some date range values from which I want to fetch last 3 month details. How can I fetch the last 3 month details?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this, Put your appropriate date column in this query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) between txtFromDate and txtToDate
```

you can check against last 90 days.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) between txtFromDate and txtToDate
```

Comment: I tried this query earlier but its not working its giving the same values present in db no filteration

Answer (score 1):

this will gives you the last 3 month date (from 1st of the month)

```
WHERE date_column >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0)
```

you have 3 date column there . . not sure which one you want use as reference

Comment: i want filter only txtToDate & txtFromDate

Comment: just change the date_column to your required table column name